# Laravel Fortify Customize Authentication Redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication, redirect, fortify, laravel-8

In Laravel fortify on customization authentication process, i can not able to redirect to login page with error message which we were able to do in Auth.
Here is the customization documentation link: https://jetstream.laravel.com/1.x/features/authentication.html#customizing-the-authentication-process

```
        if ($user && Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) && $user->status == 'active') {
            return $user;
        } elseif ($user->status == 'inactive') {
            //redirect with some error message to login blade
        } elseif ($user->status == 'blocked') {
            //redirect with some error message to login blade
        }
```

Please help me out on this.

Comment: that method is only for returning the user, so you can't do any redirect in there .... you can return `null` or `false`, but you won't have any custom message

Comment: but in case of returning message to user how i can do it here in fortify?

Answer (score 9):

For those coming from google search who use `Laravel Jetstream` (which uses Fortify):
`Snapey` of Laracasts [answered this question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-to-intended-url-jetstream-fortify) and made a [tutorial](https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/laravel-8-conditional-login-redirects) which uses your own `LoginResponse` to override the default login behavior.

I made mine like this but of course you should create your own according to your needs.

```
// app/Http/Responses/LoginResponse.php
namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{

    /**
     * @param  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function toResponse($request)
    {
        // replace this with your own code
        // the user can be located with Auth facade
        
        $home = Auth::user()->is_admin ? config('fortify.dashboard') : config('fortify.home');
            
        return $request->wantsJson()
            ? response()->json(['two_factor' => false])
            : redirect($home);
    }

}
```

The next step it to modify `JetstreamServiceProvider` to use your `LoginReponse`

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->configurePermissions();

    Jetstream::deleteUsersUsing(DeleteUser::class);

    // register new LoginResponse
    $this->app->singleton(
        \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse::class,
        \App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse::class
    );
}
```

Hope it saves you time.

Answer (score 9):

for example - custom redirect after login/logout/register. By request parameter - alias

In FortifyServiceProvider class

Add.

```
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse;
```

And then in register method.

```
    $this->app->instance(LogoutResponse::class, new class implements LogoutResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            return redirect('/'.$request->alias);
        }
    });

    $this->app->instance(LoginResponse::class, new class implements LoginResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            return redirect()->intended('/'.$request->alias.'/admin/dashboard');
        }
    });

    $this->app->instance(RegisterResponse::class, new class implements RegisterResponse {
        public function toResponse($request)
        {
            return redirect('/'.$request->alias.'/admin/dashboard');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Best approach... worked like a charm!

Comment: This is the correct way, documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/fortify#customizing-authentication-redirects

Answer (score 8):

I understand your frustration with the documentation (or lack thereof). I had a similar problem and this is how I managed to do it:

```
if ($user && in_array($user->status_id, [1,2,3])) {
    if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)) {
        return $user;
    }
}
else {
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        Fortify::username() => "Username not found or account is inactive. Please check your username.",
    ]);
}
```

https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/94#issuecomment-700777994

Comment: This really helped in checking user roles before logging a user in

Answer (score 6):

For SPA applications that only want a custom JSON response rather than the default `{two_factor: false}`.

Create a custom response that implements `LoginResponse` contract of Fortify (in this case I'm returning the user object):

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Responses;

use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LoginResponse implements LoginResponseContract
{
    public function toResponse($request): Response
    {
        return response()->json(auth()->user());
    }
}
```

Add this line to the boot method of `FortifyServiceProvider`:

```
$this->app->singleton(LoginResponseContract::class, LoginResponse::class);
```

Making sure you've imported the namespaces correctly:

```
use App\Http\Responses\LoginResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse as LoginResponseContract;
```

If you are still not getting a JSON from the server, make sure your request has the right headers. It should be an XHR request that accepts `application/json`.

Inspired by [this](https://laravel-news.com/override-login-redirects-in-jetstream-fortify) article from Laravel News.

Answer (score 1):

goto \config\fortify.php at line 66, change  home value to any path you want

'home' => '/dashboard',

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Fortify doesn't have a way to customize redirects.

There is an open issue requesting this bahavior here: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/77

There is a good chance this will be added soon!