# Getting laravel to use a different route when logging in

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to do this thing where if the user logging is an admin then Laravel needs to send them to the admin route and if the user is a customer then it needs to send them to the customer route.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083589/6472849

Comment: I tried that out and all I'm getting is a blank page with no errors

Answer (score 0):

users table add new column role different role admin user and customer
and login controller check role and return view with different route

```
    $user= Auth::user()->role;
      if ($user->admin){
       return redirect()->route('')
        }else if($user->user){
       return redirect()->route('')
       }else{
       return redirect()->route('')
         }
```

Comment: I'm using jetstream and inertia